# Question that involves an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can someone help me to answer the following question:

I we have  $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exist a constant $C_{\epsilon }>0$ such that: $\forall u\in C_0^{\infty}(R^{2n})$

$<a(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>+<b(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>-<c(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>\le \epsilon <a(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>+C_{\epsilon } ||u||_{L^2(R^{2n})}$

with $<a(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>\ge 0$ and $<b(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>\ge 0 \forall u\in C_0^{\infty}(R^{2n})$ but we dont no the sign of $<c(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>$.

Is it true that we can deduce that there exist $ C>0$ such that :$\forall u\in C_0^{\infty}(R^2n)$

$<a(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>+<b(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>-<c(x,y)u(x,y),u(x,y)>\le C||u||_{L^2(R^{2n})}?$

Thanks .

Comment: What do $a$, $b$ and $c$ represent?

Comment: we only know that $a,b$ and $c$ are three functions that depend of (x,y) vaiables